# How to trigger an API call once the application is loaded

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-observable, redux-router

I am using the stack React/Redux/Redux-observable/Redux-router.

I would like to get information about the current user (or to trigger a redirect to the authentication portal if not logged) against a rest api so that I can show an appropriate screen when launching the application.

I can't find any proper way to do this as my problem is that I don't know when/where to trigger these actions.

Comment: where do you plan to have API calls initiated... in Redux actions, or in the React components, or elsewhere?

Comment: I plan to do everything from where it should be done: epics. But if there no other alternative but to do it somewhere else, I'll go for it.

Comment: ah hah.... missed observable. Since I don't use it, I doubt any "should" from me would fit.  Good luck.

Comment: What would have been your suggestion with something else than redux observable?

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you a redux example because I'm not familiar with observables.

You can dispatch the action to retrieve user information in the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method of your Root component, and render the proper part of your UI based on what's received.

Or you can always render the router and dispatch proper navigation action in the middleware based on what you receive for `getUserInfo`.

```
class Root extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getUserInfo();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      {this.props.userLoggedIn ? <LoggedInUI /> : <LoginPage />}
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  userLoggedIn: state.user.loggedIn,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = {
  getUserInfo,
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Root);
```

Comment: This can't work for me. The connection page is on a different server as it is based on oauth authentication. Moreover my preference is to leave my components and containers as stupid as possible as the logic should be in epics.